# How to fetch records having multiple rows with different column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I have a table disp table. Which has 3 columns, service_code, row_status and business_unit_id.

| service_code | row_status | business_unit_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | BU1 |
| A | 0 | BU2 |
| A | 0 | BU3 |
| B | 1 | BU1 |
| B | 0 | BU2 |
| C | 0 | BU2 |
| C | 0 | BU3 |

I need a query that will fetch me service_code which is 100% row_status = 0 across all the business_unit_id. So in the above case the answer should be C.
The table that i am working on has millions of records. How can i figure out which service_code has row_status = 0 at every business_unit_id?
I have written a query but it seems its returning A, B, C. That is not correct.

```
create table #tmpTable (pc_ccs_9xx_service_code varchar(10));
create table #tmpTable1 (pc_ccs_9xx_service_code varchar(10));

insert into #tmpTable
select top 500 
pcdis.service_code
from pc_ccs_9xx_deposit_install_service pcdis
where pcdis.row_status = 1
order by pcdis.service_code asc

select * from #tmpTable

insert into #tmpTable1
select top 500 pcdis.service_code from pc_ccs_9xx_deposit_install_service pcdis
join #tmpTable tt on tt.pc_ccs_9xx_service_code = pcdis.service_code and pcdis.row_status = 1
order by pcdis.service_code asc

select top 500 tt.pc_ccs_9xx_service_code from #tmpTable tt
join #tmpTable1 tt1 on --tt1.pc_ccs_9xx_service_code = tt.pc_ccs_9xx_service_code and 
tt1.pc_ccs_9xx_service_code not in (select top 100 pc_ccs_9xx_service_code from #tmpTable)
order by tt.pc_ccs_9xx_service_code asc

DROP table #tmpTable
DROP table #tmpTable1
```

Comment: Note that a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results.

Comment: Thanks I have made the change to the query. But the underlying problem still remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH YOUR_TABLE_DATA (service_code,row_status,business_unit_id)AS
(
  SELECT 'A',   1,  'BU1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' ,  0,  'BU2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' ,  0,  'BU3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B',   1,  'BU1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B',   0,  'BU2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C',   0,  'BU2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' ,  0,  'BU3'
)
SELECT C.service_code
FROM YOUR_TABLE_DATA AS C
GROUP BY C.service_code
HAVING MIN(C.row_status)=MAX(C.row_status)
AND MIN(C.row_status)=0
```

Please try this query.

Comment: A good answer contains an explanation as well as a solution.

Comment: This query is running within 35 secs. Hence marking this as answer. Thank you for your response. Really saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM your_table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM your_table tt 
        WHERE tt.service_code = t.service_code
          AND tt.row_status <> 0);
```

You can also use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` as follows:

```
SELECT t.service_code
  FROM your_table t
GROUP BY t.service_code
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t.row_status <> 0 THEN 1 END) = 0;

-- If your row_status contains 0 or positive numbers only 
-- then use following HAVING clause
HAVING SUM(t.row_status) = 0;
```

Comment: This query is also correct and returning the same results. But its taking more than 1min 30 secs to respond. So based on the performance i marked the answer. Thank you so much for responding. I learnt alot from you guys today.